# Doxygen - Could NOT find FLEX (missing: FLEX_EXECUTABLE)

Tags: cmake, doxygen, flex-lexer, apt

I know there are very similar worded questions on here, but I could not find an answer to my question there, so here we go:
I'm trying to see which of my C++ methods are called by others so I found Doxygen after googling.
On their [page](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html) the installation seems pretty straightforward:

> If you have the necessary build tools installed (i.e. g++, python,
>   cmake, flex, bison), you should do the following to get the initial
>   copy of the repository:
>
> `git clone https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen.git`
>   `cd doxygen`
>   `mkdir build`
>   `cd build`
>   `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..`
>   `make`

Until `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..` everything goes well, then on that command following error occurs:

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~/doxygen/build$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find FLEX (missing: FLEX_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindFLEX.cmake:230 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:84 (find_package)
```

I thought: *No big deal*, why should anything work out of the box...seems I have to install `flex`.
So I do:
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install flex`
`sudo apt autoremove` (because after installation the command line recommended me to do this)

Now it seems to me that flex has been installed, I try `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..` again...same error. I close the command line, start it up again, try it again - same error...
So now I'm slowly gettin' pissed and turn to Stack Overflow for help :D
What am I doing wrong???

And because I saw someone asking this in the other question's comment, here's the output of `flex`:

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~/doxygen/build$ flex
The program 'flex' can be found in the following packages:
 * flex
 * flex-old
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Comment: Message "The program 'flex' can be found in the following packages:" means that flex is **not installed**. Probably, `apt autoremove` removes it.

Comment: Thanks, I so I will try the install steps again, leaving out that last part...

Comment: @Tsyvarev this indeed fixed my problem - you can post it as an answer if you like - the thing is still not working completetly but I will google it first and I'll have to post another question for that anyway, because it's a different problem now.

Comment: Hm, the problem seems to be with using `apt` for install the package, which is not a *programming* problem...

Comment: @Tsyvarev maybe this question should be moved to the 'AskUbuntu' Forum, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, you may move it to AskUbuntu. But before that, make the question to be about `apt` and its using. E.g. "Why 'apt autoremove' removes explicitely installed package". Make sure to check that no questions about that problem has already asked.

Comment: I'm gonna delete this question then, migration is not that easy as it seems and only worth it for really good questions a shown here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253869/can-we-have-more-options-in-the-closing-off-topic-migration

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be in AskUbuntu I believe

Comment: I would not close it as it gives the warning for other users that use the same procedure and will see that thère might be a problem with `sudo apt autoremove

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It seems like `apt autoremove` really removed the package I just installed in the previous step.
So what worked for me was:

```
git clone https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen.git
cd doxygen
mkdir build
cd build
```

These are new:

---

```
sudo apt-get install flex
sudo apt-get install bison
```

---

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make
```

...but of course the horror wouldn't end there, see [my next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50986430/4120196) :D