# doxygen INSTALL cannot copy file ".../doxygen/build/bin/doxygen" to "/usr/local/bin/doxygen"

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-14.04, doxygen

After solving some [initial problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50986047/4120196) while trying to get doxygen to work I stumbled upon the next error while following the [doxygen install tutorial](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html).
What worked so far:
`git clone https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen.git`
`cd doxygen`
`mkdir build`
`cd build`
`sudo apt-get install flex` (it was missing so I had to install it before `cmake`)
`sudo apt-get install bison`(it was missing so I had to install it before `cmake`)
`cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..`
`make`

But then on `make install` I get following error:

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~/doxygen/build$ make install
[  1%] Built target md5
[ 19%] Built target qtools
[ 24%] Built target vhdlparser
[ 92%] Built target _doxygen
[ 98%] Built target doxycfg
[100%] Built target doxygen
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/doxygen
CMake Error at src/cmake_install.cmake:42 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file "/home/test/doxygen/build/bin/doxygen" to
  "/usr/local/bin/doxygen".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:40 (include)



Makefile:148: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

What are the steps I probably need to do to get rid of this error?

> Edit
>   I checked the two paths, the first one exists and the other one has following permissions:

```
test@test-VirtualBox:/usr/local$ ls -la
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Apr  2 00:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Feb 28 19:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 28 19:25 bin
```

Comment: For Ubuntu there is also a precompiled package, see doxygen.org, can you use this (should be sufficient for your initial tests)? Regarding the erro ryou checked that /home/test/doxygen/build/bin/doxygen is present and that the directory /usr/local/bin exists and is writable for you ?

Comment: @albert `/home/test/doxygen/build/bin/doxygen` exists, how can I check if the other directory is writable for me?

Comment: ls -ls /usr/local/bin and check the permissions. Other alternative is touch /usr/local/bin/dummy_dummy and see if this gives and error or not (when not writable and remove the file again with rm /usr/local/bin/dummy_dummy)

Comment: @albert We're getting there: `test@test-VirtualBox:/usr/local$ touch /usr/local/bin/dummy_dummy
touch: cannot touch '/usr/local/bin/dummy_dummy': Permission denied`

Comment: As usual, use `sudo make install` for install the package into system-wide location.

Comment: @albert Thank you, it solved the problem - you can post it as an answer if you like :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding the installation, check also the permissions of the destination directory (default /usr/local/bin) when not the right permissions use:
`sudo  make install`